# JNI using env->GetStringUTFChars() in return statement

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNICALL where I pass a jstring to C++ that needs to be passed to a C++ funciton that gets me a value.
Is it possible to call GetStringUTFChars in the return statement. My concern is, that I can not call ReleaseStringUTFChars to free up the memory.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_TestClass_getValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring name){
    return t1->getValue(env->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0));
}
```

It works , but I am not sure If I will get memory leaks or a stackoverflow.

The only other option I see is to do something like that:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_TestClass_getValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring name){
    const char* nameChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, nameChars);
    return t1->getValue(nameChars);
}
```

But that might be even worse. Because according to [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#ReleaseStringUTFChars) ReleaseStringUTFChars

> informs the VM that the native code no longer needs access to utf

In my case access to `const char* nameChars`.
But as I need to pass `nameChars` i would try to access already freed or about to be freed variables.

I would like the first version to be correct. If not, what would you suggest?
Is memory from heap allocated even when a variable is not declared?

Comment: How about `auto result = t1->getValue(nameChars);  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, nameChars); return result;`? Or write a helper class that gets the data from a `jstring` and releases it when the object falls out of scope.

Comment: This is what RAII is meant to solve:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii

Comment: RAII can generate code that is safe in either scenario, but the question, I think, is whether `GetStringUTFChars` returns a [local or global reference](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/refs.html), or whether that mechanism is even applicable to a `char const*`. I don't think it is, but I'm not entirely certain; the documentation is not very clear on this point.

Comment: _"the question, I think, is whether `GetStringUTFChars` returns a local or global reference"_. Neither AFAIK. `GetStringUTFChars` allocates some memory, copies the strings contents to that memory (doing UTF16 to UTF8 conversion in the process), and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. `ReleaseStringUTFChars` calls `free` on that memory, hence the reason why you need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars`.